# Determining the original recording date of a video file

Tags: ffmpeg, encoder, exiftool

I received a video file that I am trying to determine when the video was originally recorded. The file is a .mov video that is muxed with an audio file. The EXIF data shows multiple creation/modification dates which I recognize as the dates that the file was saved to my local computer, but the last creation date shown is from an earlier date that is adjusted to Eastern Time (UTC -4), which I believe may be the date the file was originally recorded. However, for that earliest creation date, it shows Lavf58.20.100 as the Encoder tag which I am unsure if that earlier creation date is just the date the video file was muxed or if it is in fact the date the video was originally recorded.

I used exiftool v. 12.44 to view the EXIF data from the video and attempted to validate the results against other known video and image files. In doing so, the last creation dates displayed on my known files were consistent with the dates the original files were recorded, however, they lacked the Lavf58.20.100 Encoder tag. I ran additional files that were muxed using FFMPEG, which show the Lavf Encoder tag, but those files did not return Creation Dates. Included is the screen capture of the EXIF data from the .mov file I am trying to determine its original recording date.

[image: EXIF Data]

Answer (score 0):

First a minor nitpick.  Not all metadata is EXIF data.  Your output shows mostly [Quicktime data](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/QuickTime.html) (and file system data), which is the standard used in video.  EXIF data can exist in a video file, but it is non-standard.

Because a lot of video editing programs do not copy or save metadata when creating new files, it can be hard, if not impossible to know the original date of a video file. For example, using ffmpeg at any point in the workflow without including the `-map_metadata` option will strip the file of all embedded metadata.

The fact that `CreationDate` still exists and that the `Track*Date` and `Media*Date` tags, as well as the `CreateDate`/`ModifyDate` tags have values at all indicates a better quality program was used with this file.  But that still depends upon what happened further upsteam in the workflow.

Your output is missing a lot of data due to the fact that many video tags are duplicates with the same name.  This especially pertains to the `Track*Date` and `Media*Date` tags, as there would be copies of these for every track, meaning there would be at least one set for the video track and one set for the audio track, more if there are additional tracks.

Run this command on your file to see all the date/time related tags in the file, including duplicates and the groups they belong to. It is a variation of the command from [exiftool FAQ #3](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q3), (always use the FAQ #3 command).  From there you can try and determine what the original date was, if it is possible.  Also note that most of these time stamps are supposed to be set to UTC, though the accuracy of that depends upon the program that created the file in the first place
`exiftool -time:all -G1 -a -s file.mov`